# create a function providing the same result as lapply in R

Tags: r, algorithm, lapply

I'm trying to analyze the efficiency of the lapply function in R, but I didn't find the original developing code of lapply in the folder "base", so I wrote a simple code by myself.

```
new_lapply<-function(data,f_name){
  list<-list()
  for (i in length(data)){
   list[i]<-f_name(data[,i])
  }
  return (list)
}
check<-Boston[1:10,]
lapply(check,length)

new_lapply(check,length)

Error: could not find function "f_name"
```

I wonder how to input a "general function name" in to a function, so I could run different functions in the new_lapply function, similar as the built-in lapply().

Thank you so much.

Comment: Are you sure that's the error you get when you run the code above? That does not seem right. How is `Boston` defined? That code should work.

Comment: Boston is a built-in data in Rstudio. The code works after I add the f_name <- match.fun(f_name) RC mentioned below. Thank you for the answer. :)

Comment: But that shouldn't be required. Match.fun will help turn character values into functions but you are passing in a function in this example. Are you running something different than what you have included above?

Comment: You are right! I deleted that line and the code still works. Thank you!!

Comment: So what was the problem? Did you just have a typo? This question as written still doesn't match up to the error.

Comment: First, It should be for (i in 1:length(data)), also, the function works when I use new_lapply(check,sum), but the function still has an error when I use new_lapply(check,length) (Error: could not find function "f_name").  If I added the match.fun line, both of the two functions works. I'm confused now... It may depend on the function...

Comment: Maybe you've defined your own variable named `length` that's masking the base function of the same name. That's something you should try to avoid.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you. I do have a variable named length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `match.fun()`.  I've made a couple of other changes too.  Hopefully this gets you in the right direction.  Also, there's a good explanation of `lapply()` and its efficiency [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functionals.html#lapply)

```
new_lapply <- function(data, f_name) {
    ## match the function in the 'f_name' argument
    f_name <- match.fun(f_name)
    ## allocate a list the same length as 'data' (ncol for data frames)
    List <- vector("list", length(data))
    for (i in seq_along(data)) {
        List[[i]] <- f_name(data[[i]])
    }
    ## if 'data' has names, carry them over to 'List' 
    if(!is.null(names(data))) 
        names(List) <- names(data)
    List
}

identical(lapply(mtcars, length), new_lapply(mtcars, length))
# [1] TRUE

um <- unname(mtcars)
identical(lapply(um, length), new_lapply(um, length))
# [1] TRUE
```